# H2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for trigger passed in classpath

Tags: java, database, triggers, h2

I'm starting the h2 server using this command:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx512M -Xss1024K -cp "C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target;C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin\h2-1.4.199.jar" org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 80 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir C:/database/h2/data
```

where in `C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target` I got jar where is my trigger class(I checked with the total commander, and I'm 100% sure it is there)

Then I open my h2 database and try to run sql on table for which I have set up trigger, but it throws:

```
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Class "com.test.projecta.trigger.Trigger" not found [90086-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194).
```

Why is it thrown? As I understand trigger should be added to classpath and it is, so why it is not seen?

Comment: Error code 90086-174 indicates that it was thrown from H2 1.3.174, so you are not connected to your server with H2 1.4.199, but use some other installation of H2.

Comment: My fault, I was checking if I will have same problem with other h2 versions and by mistake I copied error from the time when I was checking it with 1.3.174. For 1.4.199 error code is [90086-199]. I will update my question with correct error code. Sorry

Comment: Do you have `C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target\com\test\projecta\trigger\Trigger.class`?

Comment: What I have is: C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target\classes\com\test\projecta\trigger\Trigger.class   + of course in C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target a jar ModuleA.jar

Comment: Then you need to include `C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target\classes` to the classpath of H2 instead of `C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target` (or a compiled jar with this class).

Comment: I already tried. Unfortunately it did not helped. I also tried to pass entire path like "C:\workspaces\ProjectA\ModuleA\target\classes\com\test\projecta\trigger\Trigger.class" and it did not helped either.

Comment: Solved: It was the problem with the way I was connecting to the database.I was specifying entire path like jdbc:h2:C:\database\h2\data\database to it instead of doing it this way jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:80/database. Nevertheless, Thank You for Your help Evgenij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It was the problem with the way I was connecting to the database.I was specifying JDBC URL like jdbc:h2:C:\database\h2\data\database instead of doing it this way jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:80/database